# How can I get a flight with a supersonic plane?

Tags: air-travel, activities, central-europe, aircraft

My dream is to fly with a supersonic plane. Since the Concorde is no longer active, I don't think it is possible to do this with a regular plane. So how can I get onto board of a supersonic plane? Ideally it should be in Central Europe.

Comment: @Stuart - I know you've looked into this ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo Matt, being a Concorde buff tells me Air France still has a working/ airworthy airframe that they technically could put back into service at some point - However I suspect it will more likely only be used at air shows, if at all.

Comment: I don't feel it warrants an answer, so a comment instead.  [Aerion](http://www.aerionsupersonic.com/) has announced a new business jet with supersonic capabilities.  They started taking orders - but it'll probably be a few more years before their AS2 enters service.  Once it's in service though, you theoretically could charter a supersonic business jet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few companies in South Africa and I think the USA that offer rides in old military jets to wealthy tourists. Same can be had in Russia and maybe some other former Soviet republics. 
South African prices for supersonic flights start at 11000 Euro.
In central Europe, laws typically prohibit supersonic flight except over open water, and even there it's severely restricted to a few narrow corridors reserved for active military aircraft (not counting military emergencies like scrambled fighters to intercept unidentified aircraft of course).

Those are your only options, as (as you said) there are no supersonic airliners left in service anywhere and other supersonic civilian aircraft have never existed (there was a plan for a supersonic business jet several years ago from Sukhoi in cooperation with I think Boeing, but it never entered even prototype stage).
http://www.incredible-adventures.com/capetown.html
http://www.kapstadt.de/jets/ (looks to be be the same company)

Answer (score 17):

**Fly a Russian MiG-29**

There is a company [MigFlug](http://www.migflug.com/en/jet-fighter-flights.html) that offers flights in Russian MiG-29 fighter jets. They offer five locations within Europe, but with the prevention of supersonic flights in Europe, you may have to go for their central Russia location.

They actually only advertise near-supersonic speeds, but maybe a few rubels more get you over the threshold. Those MiGs are certainly very capable of supersonic flights.

They don't mention any prices on their web site, you have to contact them.

Comment: There is a company in Russia that does supersonic (depending on conditions, your health and the package you book up to mach 2) they also offer a trip to the edge of space (above 60,000 ft) in a Mig 29. I enquired about the price for the edge of space about a year ago £20,000 two years earlier it was only £6000. 

http://www.incredible-adventures.com/edge-of-space-intro.html

Comment: that company is MigFlug :) Wanted to mention them but couldn't find their website.