# Riding in a military jet

Tags: where-on-earth, extreme-tourism, aircraft

I remember that there was a possibility that one could take a ride in a military MiG.  I think at one point the cost was $15k.

Are there any other places that would allow a person to take such a ride?

Comment: See here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/how-can-i-get-a-flight-with-a-supersonic-plane

Comment: @DJClayworth Which refers you back to the MiGs for the most part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting a ride in an ex-military jet is totally doable; pilots love to fly, and it's even better when someone else is footing the bill. Ex-military aircraft in private ownership are often called "warbirds", and searching for that term will provide many leads.  Here's one:

> http://www.warbirdalley.com/fly.htm
>
> Take a ride in a warbird! Here are links to various organizations which actively operate warbird aircraft, including pay-per-flight operations and museums. We've also listed a few miscellaneous other ways to get some hands-on flight experience with these exciting airplanes.

Or:

> http://www.flyfighterjet.com/
>
> You can fly a jet fighter such as the Supersonic MiG-29 Fulcrum interceptor, the Aero L-39 Albatros or the Hawker Hunter fighter-bomber aircraft. We offer fighter jet rides from various airfields all over the World.
> This is no simulation: Here you can book a real jet fighter ride in a military aircraft

If you're serious, you could even troll the [FAA aircraft registration database](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/) for exotic planes, and contact the owners directly (or use your findings for more targetted googling). Another fruitful technique would be to simply google for particular aircraft types. For example, the [L-39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_L-39_Albatros) is a Czechloslovak jet trainer of which there are many in private hands. Googling reveals the existence of the [L-39 Enthusiasts](http://www.l39.com/) group, which could certainly direct you to a pilot happy to give you a ride.  One site quotes **$3000 for a 45 minute ride**.

Finally, aviation is sometimes a bit old-fashioned, and the best way to find what you want is often to simply show up at the airport and ask around.  Someone will know someone and soon you will find your way into the cockpit of a warbird.

Answer (score 9):

In Germany, at the [Bitburg Aiprort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitburg_Airport), the former [Bitburg Air Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitburg_Air_Base), there is such a possibility. Well, they don't have MiG's, but you can have a flight on an [L-39 Albatros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_L-39_Albatros), a trainer aircraft. There is [a website in German](http://www.L-39.de/). If want you to have more information, you can try to [contact](http://web.me.com/christopherblatt/Aero_L-39_Albatros/Kontakt.html) the guys.

Answer (score 5):

[adrenalin.com.au](http://www.adrenalin.com.au/air/jet-fighters/)  has some offers for Australia, and you have the choice between a L-39 fighter jet and a [A37B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_A-37_Dragonfly) ex-military jet.

Prices between AUD 1,200 (15mins flight) and AUD 2,700 (35mins flight) at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

German event organizer Jochen Schweizer offers [flying a MiG 29](http://www.jochen-schweizer.de/geschenke/mig,default,pd.html) in Nizhniy Novgorod for 14.5k EUR.

bestrussiantour.com has an offer for [flying a MiG 29 and/or Mig 31](http://www.bestrussiantour.com/jet_flights/tour_over_nizhny) at the same place, with a price list for download.

Comment: Thanks but MiGs ans Sukhoi I already know about.

Answer (score 1):

[Ken Thompson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson) wrote an [article about flying a MiG29](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/who/ken/mig.html) in Moscow. He booked the flight via a Miami based organization called Fly-With-Us. The article is a fun read, though possibly a bit dated: I discovered it many years ago.

Comment: There are multiple places you could get a flight on a MiG.   I was specifically looking for other options

Answer (score 1):

[There is a company in Florida](http://www.aurora-aerospace.com/) that uses L39 Albatross planes and others for NASA type astronaut training.