# Are there any places in the US where I can drive a tank?

Tags: usa, military

I know I've asked about possibility of flying in a [military fighter jet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/riding-in-a-military-jet) before but going through some of my old answers I discovered that [you can take a tour driving a tank](http://stayinkiev.com/en/tank-driving).  Well this is actually a [БТР](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTR-3) which isn't a tank but is still cool!

Any places in US I can do the same?

**EDIT**

[Apparently actual tank driving is also possible](http://stayinkiev.com/en/tour-to-the-ukrainian-military-base)

Comment: I disagree that tanks are cooler than jets, but +1 anyway— paves the way for me to ask about submarines next ;).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can!

[Drive a Tank](http://driveatank.com/) in [Kasota, Minnesota](http://goo.gl/maps/nkoP9) is the place you want to go to, since a former competitor in Texas (Texas Tank Adventure) has apparently closed their doors.

> Drive A Tank is a family owned and operated business in Kasota,
>   Minnesota, USA.   Here you can experience real armored tanks up close
>   and personal, get behind the controls and attempt to navigate our
>   densley wooded course. You can even crush a car or two! We have a
>   number of U.S. vehicles and several imported British M.B.T.s, S.P.G.s,
>   and A.P.C.s!    Afterwards, sample a few of our fully automatic
>   machine guns in our indoor shooting range. Our state of the art
>   facility is capable of handling up to .50 caliber ammunition.

For those who live too far from Minnesota, there are possibilities in [New Zealand](http://www.tanksforeverything.co.nz/), [Germany](http://www.panzerkutscher.de/en/index.htm), and the [UK](http://tankdrivingscotland.com/driving-experiences/tank-driving/) as well, to name just a few.

Just remember: Tanks aren't built for comfort, so if a seriously bumpy ride leaves you with horrible headaches, then this may not be for you - or you need to bring your painkillers.

Comment: You can't do better then someone advertising you in [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/larryolmsted/2012/08/15/drive-a-tank-add-this-incredibly-fun-experience-to-your-bucket-list/)

Comment: Well.  Actually you can.  Someone advertising you here...